# Where to find online documentation for older versions of Swift?

Tags: swift

Is there an official online Apple source for documentation for Swift 3? (Preferably that can be accessed without signing in to a developer account.) Browser searches for "Swift 3" are finding links to documentation for Swift 4 at developer.apple.com, but I am interested in the older version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a modern Apple Device, which you must be in order to develop with Swift 3, you can use iBooks' Swift 3.1 Guide. Once Xcode 9 and Swift 4 are finalized, this book may receive an update to Swift 4, but you should be able to decline the update.
Check out the book here: [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11)

Comment: Yes, I have a copies of the Swift 2 and Swift 3 iBooks already. But still wondering whether there is a way to access the Swift 3 versions of what is now showing up as Swift 4 when you look for Swift info in the documents at developer.apple.com.